# Почему при каждом нажатии на кнопку удаляются все элементы из List?

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, asp.net-webforms

Есть такая форма.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На форме есть поле `List <int> numberOfProducts` В который я хочу занести информацию о количестве товара, добавленного в корзину. То есть при нажатии кнопку Добавить в список должен добавиться элемент `int 2`

Вот что на этим этапе показывает отладчик
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что хорошо. Но Когда я добавляю еще один товар в список, то `numberOfProducts` полностью обнуляется.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне надо передать заполненный `numberOfProducts` на другую страницу по нажатию на кнопку `"Квитанция"`, но там он почему-то хранит 0 элементов. Добавление информации о количестве реализовал в соответствующих кнопках, вместе с заполнением `ListBox товары к оплате`

```
   namespace WebApplication1
   {   
   public partial class ShopForm : System.Web.UI.Page
   {
   protected List<int> numberOfProducts = new List<int>();
        // Заполняем товары к оплате
        Basket.Items.Add(new ListItem(productList.SelectedItem.Text, productList.SelectedItem.Value));
        int count;
        // количество товаров
        if (numberTextBox.Text != "" && int.TryParse(numberTextBox.Text, out count))
        {
            numberOfProducts.Add(count);
        }
        else numberOfProducts.Add(1);
    }
    }
    }
```

Почему мой List  каждый раз обнуляется? Как это исправить?

Comment: Ваш код, что вы показываете, просто невалиден, он не скомпилируется.

Comment: Ну и советую вам почитать про жизненный цикл страницы asp.net + что нибудь про viewstate

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET создает объект страницы заново при каждом запросе к веб-серверу. Переменные экземпляра, соответственно, при этом теряются. Статические переменные, возможно, будут сохраняться, но их время жизни ограничено временем жизни домена приложения, поэтому в них хранить состояние также нельзя - оно будет теряться в моменты, когда IIS перезагружает домен приложений. Чтобы надежно хранить состояние, можно воспользоваться одним из следующих методов:

1. Хранение на стороне клиента: [ViewState](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.viewstate?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_UI_Control_ViewState)
2. Хранение на стороне сервера: [Application State](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178594%28v%3dvs.100%29), [Session State](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178581%28v%3dvs.100%29)
3. Хранение во внешней базе данных (в сочетании с каким-либо из способов первой группы для сопоставления данных клиенту)

Пример работы с ViewState:

```
ViewState["list"] = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };

//...

var list = ViewState["list"];
```

Выбор между разными способами определяется объемом информации, насколько долго ее нужно хранить, требованиями к нагрузке сетевого соединения и ресурсов сервера. Способы из первой группы приводят к повышенной нагрузке на сетевое соединение, так как данные передаются туда-сюда с каждым запросом, и при закрытии страницы в браузере данные потеряются. Способы из второй группы позволяют сохранять данные между разными заходами на страницу, и больше нагружают сервер. Третья группа позволяет переложить нагрузку на внешний сервер СУБД, а также самостоятельно управлять временем жизни (как правило, используется в сочетании с аутентификацией, чтобы можно было сохранять данные даже между заходами с разных устройств).

Подробнее о способах хранения состояния можно прочитать здесь: [ASP.NET State Management Recommendations](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/previous-versions/aspnet/z1hkazw7(v=vs.100))